# junk character in multi string registry field in win2003 server

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

I have written to code to read and write to registry which is working fine in all the OS except the win2003. Basically after setting value in registry(RegSetValueExW) I am able to read it correctly (RegQueryValueExW). But when i open regedit, i see some junk characters in it.

open using

```
RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, subKey , 0, KEY_WRITE | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &_regKey);
```

to set: (value is wstring)

```
::RegSetValueExW(_regKey, key, NULL, REG_MULTI_SZ, reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(value.c_str()), static_cast<DWORD>(value.length()*2 + 1));
```

for query:

```
::RegQueryValueExW(regKey, key, NULL, &type, reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(&value[0]), &valueLength);
```

Comment: The correct way of getting a C-style string from `std::string` is [`std::string::c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str), which you use in one case but not the other!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MSDN manual page on [`RegSetValueExW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> With the REG_MULTI_SZ data type, the string must be terminated with two **null** characters.

You need to construct a `BYTE` array containing two terminator characters and pass it to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `(value.length() + 1)*2` instead of `value.length()*2 + 1`.

Comment: that doesnt seems to be the issue